# R manipulate a list of matrices

Tags: r, list

Been stuck with this for a while!

How can I manipulate the first list into the second?

```
list("X" = X, "Y" = Y, ...)

list("X" = c(X,n), "Y" = c(Y,n), ...)
```

where X and Y are matrices and n is an integer and the lists are of unknown size. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `c(X,n)`, which coerces matrix to vector, is what you really want, then

```
lst <- list(a = matrix(1:4, 2), b = matrix(1:4, 2))
n <- 5
lapply(lst, c, n)
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
# $b
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: The idea of lapply(lst,c,n) is not natural to a beginner: thanks a lot for your very timely help!

Comment: @PatrickT this equivalent to `lapply(lst, function(x) c(x, n))`